# Ajax call getting 411 Length required error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, bearer-token

Get request of my ajax call getting 411 length required error.
My request is working fine when token is passed via  rest-client  of Firefox browser

Many thanks for your help....

```
$.ajax(
'https://example.site.net/users/me/recent',
{
type: 'GET',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer token");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  console.log('Fired prior to the request');
},
complete: function (resp) {
  console.log(resp);
}
});
```

Comment: That error is coming from your server.  Check your server-side code.

Comment: However, you probably shouldn't be sending a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I tried to access by removing Content-Type header also.But still getting same error.

Comment: Try adding `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", 0)` since you're not sending any data along with the AJAX request.

Comment: I updated my code by adding lenght header but still no luck